# I am trying to read an image with python's cv2 and save it as an array, but I get a type error

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv, python

I am trying to read an image with python's cv2 and save it as an array, but I get a type error.

I tried switching to a numpy array, but got the same error.

```py
GmdMiss_Folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..', 'Photo', 'GMD Miss')
```

```py
GmdMiss_List = os.listdir(GmdMiss_Folder)
```

```py
for i in GmdMiss_List:
    Img_Miss_List[i] = np.array(cv2.imread(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), GmdMiss_Folder, GmdMiss_List(i)), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
```

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GmdMiss_List(i)`
should be:
`GmdMiss_List[i]`

Should fix the issue.